# Python Validation function returns nonetype

Tags: python

```
print ("\n" * 100)
def weight_rep():
    rep = 0
    try:
        rep = int(input("How many times would you like to enter a weight?\n"))
        return rep
    except ValueError:
        print ("\n" * 100)
        print("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
        print("You must enter a valid number that is:\n1) Whole\n2) Positive")
        print("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
        weight_rep()
        return rep

rep = weight_rep()

weight = []

for i in range (0, (rep)):
    weightn = int(input("Please input weight " + str(i+1) +":\n"))
    weight.append(weightn)
    print (weight[i])
mean = sum(weight)/int(len(weight))
print("The average weight of these fruits is {0:.2f}g".format(mean))
```

If I enter a correct number at the first stage, this simple code carries on as expected, however, when I enter something which repeats the weight_rep() function and then enter something, the function returns nonetype

Comment: Not true. That function can't return None.

Comment: Your recursive function call result is ignored. As a result, in case of an error in the first attempt, your posted version returns `0`, *always*. You shouldn't really use recursion here anyway, see the first duplicate I point you to (reload the page).

Comment: Use `rep = weight_rep()` or just `return weight_rep()` in `except` part

Comment: @StefanPochmann: yes, I added both. I do see that the currently posted version returns `0`, not `None`, but they likely had a version that omitted the the second `return`.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
weight_rep()
return rep
```

Should become:

```
return weight_rep()
```

Although I wouldn't recommend a recursive call as you've done, the above will resolve your current problem.